# Excel Data Validation - Add only Dates with 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have in Row 4 across my columns a flag which is either 1 or 0.
Row 7 contains my dates across columns.

I am trying to do a dropdown validation for only the dates which have 1 as the flag in their column.

```
=OFFSET(LEDGER!$M$7,0,COUNTIF(LEDGER!$M$4:$CV$4,"=1"),0)
```

this doesn't seem to work. Is what I am looking do-able?

```
| 1         | 1         | 1         | 1         | 0         | 0         | 0         | 0         |   |   |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|---|---|
| 31-Dec-10 | 31-Dec-11 | 31-Dec-12 | 31-Dec-13 | 31-Dec-14 | 31-Dec-15 | 31-Dec-16 | 31-Dec-17 |   |   |
```

Comment: Maybe adding a picture might help.

Comment: please see markup table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dates starts from D7 and if the flags starts from D4 then try this formula.

> =OFFSET($D$7,0,0,,COUNTIF($D$4:$K$4,"<>0"))